# Set mount option for given mount point with ansible

Tags: linux, mount, ansible

Is there an elegant way to set the mount options for a given mount point by UUID with ansible?

What I want to accomplish is an fstab entry like this:

```
UUID=d5e3a2e2-a113-4a27-b8d7-801dbf4c6134 / ext4 errors=remount-ro,noatime,user_xattr,acl 0 1
```

So basically I want to tell ansible: "Set these options for the device on /." but the `src` parameter of the [mount module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mount_module.html) is required for the state present and I want to use the UUID as the source.

My current solution is posted as an answer below but it will loop over all existing mounts and check whether the path is `/` or not and therefore produces a lot of `skipping` outputs.

---

What I currently do is:

```
- name: "mount options for /"
  mount:
    path: "/"
    src: "UUID={{ item.uuid }}"
    fstype: "ext4"
    opts: "errors=remount-ro,noatime,user_xattr,acl"
    state: "present"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
  when: "item.mount == '/'"
```

This does what I intend to do but it checks **all** mount points of the host and therefore produces a lot of `skipping` outputs:

```
TASK [node : mount options for /] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 291684016128, u'mount': u'/', u'size_available': 215996313600, u'fstype': u'ext4', u'device': u'/dev/sda2', u'options': u'rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,acl'})
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 527433728, u'mount': u'/boot/efi', u'size_available': 523894784, u'fstype': u'vfat', u'device': u'/dev/sda1', u'options': u'rw'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 10908480831488, u'mount': u'/scr', u'size_available': 2431928762368, u'fstype': u'nfs4', u'device': u'192.168.31.3:/scratch', u'options': u'rw,vers=4,sec=sys,addr=192.168.31.3,clientaddr=192.168.31.41,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 10908480831488, u'mount': u'/homes', u'size_available': 2431928762368, u'fstype': u'nfs4', u'device': u'192.168.31.3:/u', u'options': u'rw,vers=4,sec=sys,addr=192.168.31.3,clientaddr=192.168.31.41,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 48378511622144, u'mount': u'/mnt/bigdata3', u'size_available': 5786707165184, u'fstype': u'nfs', u'device': u'192.168.31.1:/DATA3/bigdata3', u'options': u'ro,noatime,vers=3,addr=192.168.31.1,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 48378511622144, u'mount': u'/mnt/bigdata4', u'size_available': 18173101342720, u'fstype': u'nfs', u'device': u'192.168.31.1:/DATA4/bigdata4', u'options': u'ro,noatime,vers=3,addr=192.168.31.1,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 38764865912832, u'mount': u'/mnt/groupdata2', u'size_available': 7847016398848, u'fstype': u'nfs', u'device': u'192.168.31.1:/DATA2/groupdata2', u'options': u'rw,noatime,vers=3,addr=192.168.31.1,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 14776486854656, u'mount': u'/mnt/bigdata1', u'size_available': 3801819906048, u'fstype': u'nfs', u'device': u'192.168.31.1:/DATA1/bigdata1', u'options': u'ro,noatime,vers=3,addr=192.168.31.1,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 23931377418240, u'mount': u'/mnt/groupdata', u'size_available': 3801819906048, u'fstype': u'nfs', u'device': u'192.168.31.1:/DATA1/groupdata', u'options': u'rw,noatime,vers=3,addr=192.168.31.1,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 12593077944320, u'mount': u'/mnt/transfer', u'size_available': 8260916609024, u'fstype': u'nfs', u'device': u'nas:/DATA5/transfer', u'options': u'ro,noatime,vers=4.1,acl,addr=192.168.31.2,clientaddr=192.168.31.41,_netdev'}) 
skipping: [node001] => (item={u'uuid': u'N/A', u'size_total': 40888277401600, u'mount': u'/mnt/transfer2', u'size_available': 25068068405248, u'fstype': u'nfs', u'device': u'nas:/DATA5/transfer2', u'options': u'ro,noatime,vers=4.1,acl,addr=192.168.31.2,clientaddr=192.168.31.41,_netdev'})
```

This is ugly in my opinion and I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

---

**EDIT**

I found the filter [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#id18) which should be able to do what I want. However I couldn't get it to work.

On thier [example website](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) I tried this data structure (copied from `ansible_facts`):

```
{
    "ansible_mounts": [
        {
            "device": "/dev/sda2", 
            "fstype": "ext4", 
            "mount": "/", 
            "options": "rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,acl", 
            "size_available": 215995777024, 
            "size_total": 291684016128, 
            "uuid": "N/A"
        }, 
        {
            "device": "/dev/sda1", 
            "fstype": "vfat", 
            "mount": "/boot/efi", 
            "options": "rw", 
            "size_available": 523894784, 
            "size_total": 527433728, 
            "uuid": "N/A"
        }
    ]
}
```

with this query:

```
ansible_mounts[?mount == `/`]
```

and got the desired output:

```
[
  {
    "device": "/dev/sda2",
    "fstype": "ext4",
    "mount": "/",
    "options": "rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,acl",
    "size_available": 215995777024,
    "size_total": 291684016128,
    "uuid": "N/A"
  }
]
```

So I tried this in the playbook:

```
    src: "UUID={{ item.uuid }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('ansible_mounts[?mount == `/`]') }}"
```

but it fails with this message:

```
The error was: 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'uuid'
```

Comment: A moderator converted your answer to an edit. Although self-answering is perfectly fine, please don't use the Answer option add extra information to your question(s) instead please use the [EDIT](https://serverfault.com/posts/846167/edit) option for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get what I want with the [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#id18) filter:

```
- name: "mount options for /"
  mount:
    path: "/"
    src: "UUID={{ ansible_mounts | json_query('[?mount == `/`] | [0].uuid') }}"
    fstype: "ext4"
    opts: "errors=remount-ro,noatime,user_xattr,acl"
    state: "present"
```

You will need to install the package `python-jmespath`.

Answer (score 0):

The output of Ansible is intended. You instruct Ansible to loop over the mounts listed in `ansible_mounts`. The only option I see would be to `grep` the UUID of the root device and register the output. Something like this should do the trick:

```
- name: Get root device UUID.
  shell: cat /etc/fstab | grep "/\s" | cut -f1 | cut -d = -f2
  register: root_uuid

- debug:
    msg: "{{ root_uuid.stdout }}"

- name: "mount options for /"
  mount:
    path: "/"
    src: "{{ root_uuid }}"
    fstype: "ext4"
    opts: "errors=remount-ro,noatime,user_xattr,acl"
    state: "present"
```

But this attempt is probably not stable and I would not recommend to do such a thing for the sake of less noisy output of Ansible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also dislike to use `grep`. Do you see a way to use the filter [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#id18) for this? I will update my question with what I tried.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way of doing that but I wouldn't spend too much energy on this topic. Ansible is kind of not the tool to define root fstab options. IMHO in an ideal situation that setting is defined in the image to kick off your VMs.

Comment: That's most likely true, it just annoys me every time I run the playbook ;) I'm managing physical machines, so Ansible is everything I have.

Comment: My point is: You can't do everything with Ansible. Even for `raw` module you need ssh connection. So there will always something else involved. When bare metal is involved I would give http://cobbler.github.io/ a try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will take a look at cobbler.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: add nodev mount option for all LVM mounts exept root part
  mount:
    name: '{{ item.mount }}'
    src: '{{ item.device }}' # UUID not needed when LVM
    state: mounted
    fstype: '{{ item.fstype }}'
    opts: "{{ item.options |regex_replace(',nodev','') }},nodev" # Fix duplicate
  when: item.options.find("nodev") != -1 and item.device.find("mapper") != -1 and not item.mount in [ "/" ]
  with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'

- name: add nodev mount option for all non-LVM mounts exept root part
  mount:
    name: '{{ item.mount }}'
    src: 'UUID={{ item.uuid }}'
    state: mounted
    fstype: '{{ item.fstype }}'
    opts: "{{ item.options |regex_replace(',nodev','') }},nodev" # Fix duplicate
  when: item.options.find("nodev") != -1 and item.device.find("mapper") == -1 and not item.mount in [ "/" ]
  with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Select Attribute filter so that you only get what you want to see. For the sake of clarity I am just using a debug statement to show the output.

```
 - name: Check mount
   debug:
     msg:
       - item mount is {{ item.mount }}
       - item size_available is {{ item.size_available }}
   with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts|selectattr('mount', 'equalto', '/boot') }}"
   when: item.mount in [ "/boot" ]
```

Output

```
TASK [Check mount] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myserver] => (item={'mount': '/boot', 'device': '/dev/sda1', 'fstype': 'xfs', 'options': 'rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota', 'size_total': 1063256064, 'size_available': 729972736, 'block_size': 4096, 'block_total': 259584, 'block_available': 178216, 'block_used': 81368, 'inode_total': 524288, 'inode_available': 523922, 'inode_used': 366, 'uuid': '6e01d6a0-9357-4d8e-be41-51cc8fa5965b'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "item mount is /boot",
        "item size_available is 729972736"
    ]
}
```